# Conditionally parsing a string

Tags: python, string

I'm working on a small script to compile a CSV file.

I've come up with this code to combine the string.

```
site = "{}.{}".format(subdomain, fullDomain)
```

However there are some situation where the subdomain may not exist. If this is the case, the output will be ".domain.tld" which is not correct.

I was wondering if there is a condition I can add in the format instruction above, or it is simpler check the output and remove the dot at the beginning if any.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this pretty straightforward one-liner?

```
"{}{}{}".format(subdomain, '.' if subdomain else '', fullDomain)
```

And you can also name each format item like:

```
"{subdomain}{dot}{fullDomain}".format(subdomain=subdomain, 
                                      dot='.' if subdomain else '', 
                                      fullDomain=fullDomain)
```

Or, you can go this way:

```
"{}{}".format(subdomain + '.' if subdomain else '', fullDomain)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to do this with the formatting language. The best solution is probably something like

```
site = fullDomain
if subdomain is not None:
     site = subdomain + "." + site
```